# Is it possible to launch multiple js debugger independant sessions in a browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, debugging, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to debug JavaScript from a page of a website, which could be different depending on a parameter given in the url.

When I call the page `example.aspx`, the URL may contain parameters like `example.aspx?id=[id_here]`
Depending on the id parameter, the codebehind file get the information to fill the objects fields and generate different JavaScript blocks in the aspx to display them.

When accessing the page with two different id's, I would like to launch simultaneously two sessions of the debugger, attached each to the corresponding window, to spot differences, step by step.

The problem is when the debugger of one of the page pauses, the other page loading is also paused, then I can't follow simultaneously the normal flow of the two pages to spot when the treatment changes.
And I can't open the page with two different browsers, because i'll lose the session.

Is it possible to do it this way, with any debugger, or do I need to process in an other way?

I will be grateful for any response

Comment: You may be better trying to structure you page so that all the JS is not inline in the page.  There are usually ways to do so and it will be both easier to debug and more performant on load.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to do so, but as the software is not for a personal use (I'm new in the team of a software company and have to perform some updates), I have to follow the structure of the pre-existing software.  
I think I 'd rather try to log the output of the debugger(including call stack), written in a formal way, then compare them with a diff tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with 2 tabs in IE?  This doesn't work in Chrome (the debugger blocks the other tab as well) but I'm able to debug separately in IE 11.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed ! I updated to IE11, and it worked !