# Two tabs the first is stuck when you in debug mode in the second tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, virtual-machine

we have application that from one window you open new window (tab) in the browser.
this is working fine ,the problem is that if you open debugger in the second tab
the first tab (which initistate the proceess) is stuck I guess its becouse they share the same JS VM ,my question is if there is a way to overcome this issue?maybe web worker or something else...
**Any idea why does it happen and some hint to search for solution will be very helpful.**

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question some time ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254473/is-it-possible-to-launch-multiple-js-debugger-independant-sessions-in-a-browser), and using IE11 seems to work fine.

Comment: ..and btw can you explain why this dont happen in IE11?

Comment: I think it's because it instanciates a new debugger for each tab, whereas firefox and chrome use a single debugger.